# Naruto Shippuden at ep. 445 on Hulu, but movies are further. Is this due to the manga?

Tags: naruto

Spoilers if you aren't caught up.

I've never read the Naruto Manga, I started binge watching about two years ago on Hulu and finally caught up to where the anime is.

> Currently everyone is stuck in the infinite tsukuyomi except Naruto, Sakura, and Sasuke. Due to being caught up I went back and started watching all of the movies. After Road to Ninja, the next is The Last: Naruto the Movie. This seems to take place WAY after everything in the TV show.

Is this because of the Manga are so far ahead and that's why the movie is now made?

Comment: K so just read a question very similar to my own so I will change it to, if I want to start reading the manga to catch up to the movie, where are these events compared to the manga>

Answer (score 3):

First of all, The Last: Naruto the Movie is just two years after the war ended. Also I think you are okay watching The Last: Naruto the Movie already. If I remember correctly there is only about one thing you will miss and it's about

> Kakashi turning into the Hokage

The manga started somewhere in 1999 and already ended on November 10, 2014

The episode you are on should be a filler if I'm correct. So that means that the episode is not part of the main story. That means you should be in volume 70 or 71 of the manga. Also if I'm correct the main story should be taking place somewhere in or after chapter 678, which is in volume 70.

[image]
[image]

So to actually answer your question. No, the manga is not far ahead they just decided to make the movie, the manga ended about two years ago so they decided to make the movie.

Also, The Last: Naruto the Movie is just mainly focused on Naruto and Hinata and the story about how they ended up together.

Answer (score 0):

The Manga is Already Over, it ended in November of 2014, so it has been done for over a year now. The anime has been more filler than canon material for the last 2 years. There is little canon material left for them to do after the Activation of the Infinite Tsukuyomi.

Comment: thank you for he answer. I looked into the manga and the day I found this i started at ch. 670 and finished at ch. 700 and t really brought things into perspective. Maybe this season they draw a conclusion but the tsukuyomi got too far and was a weak filler. I much rather would've watched the battle the ensued and the following movies of two months as opposed to the filler they gave us. Love all of you fellow Naruto fans god bless.